# Why does `grep -L x <<<x >/dev/null` return 0 despite that `grep -L x <<<x` returns 1?

Tags: linux, grep, gnu

I have GNU grep 3.3-1 ([the current version in Debian Buster](https://packages.debian.org/stable/base/grep)).

From `man grep`:

> EXIT STATUS
>
> Normally  the  exit  status  is 0 if a line is selected, 1 if no lines were selected, and 2 if an error occurred.  However, if the `-q` or `--quiet` or `--silent` is used and a line is selected, the exit status is 0 even if an error occurred.

This is consistent with [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html). (`-L` is not specified there.)

[Full documentation of the latest release](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) and [documentation in the latest commit](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/doc/grep.in.1?id=70517057c9234146d56bb05cc22cd62ab6407c86) don't have more details about `-L` (`--files-without-match`).

`grep -L x <<<x` (in `bash`) exits with code 1. I'm not sure if this is consistent with the documentation (what exactly are selected lines here?), but at least this is explainable: no input file has matched the condition that there must be no `x`.

`grep -Lq x <<<x` and `grep -L x <<<x >/dev/null` both exit with code 0. Okay, `-q` is a tiny bit more understandable, but why stdout redirection affects exit code? So to get the original exit-code behavior while suppressing output, a hack like `(set -o pipefail; /bin/grep -L x <<<x | cat >/dev/null)` is needed. Why is that?

Since GNU grep is so widely-used, I'm not sure that this is a bug in `grep`: it's more likely that I miss something. Or maybe exit code of `-L` is simply something not to rely on? Even though you can understand the behavior of the current version using test runs like this and source code, this behavior may change in the future since it's not consistent with the current documentation. What do you think?

(By the way, [tests in the latest commit](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/tests?id=70517057c9234146d56bb05cc22cd62ab6407c86) don't seem to test `-L` other than for a non-2 exit code (in `in-eq-out-infloop`) and for edge cases like `-f /dev/null` (in `skip-read`).)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [a bug](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-grep/2019-10/msg00006.html), which was [fixed in GNU `grep` 3.4](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/NEWS?id=e84a2ea9d2fb820d0af60f9632f869bcd5edd93a#n115):

> The exit status of 'grep -L' is no longer incorrect when standard
> output is /dev/null.
>
> [Bug#37716 introduced in grep 3.2]

[This is the relevant commit](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/commit/?id=268cae478d4d1126c69efd2dcd77e9bc94cf08ba).